# POST php method is safe?

Tags: php, html, database, post

I have to pass a score integer from my C# app to a php page and then here add it to my DataBase. I pass this data by POST method and my question is: if one person knows my key-word for recover data from php POST, he can create a personal php page and send with a form an customized and illegal score to my php page and so adding it in my DB?

```
$myscore = $_POST['score'];
```

And someone knows I use **score** as a keyword  and so he can use it for a personal form that redirect to my URL and add a customized score.
There is a way to avoid it?

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
var score=document.getElementById('score').value;<br/>
var secret=document.createElement('INPUT');<br/>
secret.setAttribute("type", "hidden");<br/>
secret.value=score;<br/>
score.value=fake value;<br/>
```

then send the secret via post method